# How to set items in adapter onclicklistener temporary to null? And later set it back?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview with items from the adapter. And when I try and retrieve new information, I'm putting a RelativeLayout with loading images and stuff on top of it.

The problem is, is that my listview and adapter items are still clickable. They can only be clickable after the loading is done. When the loading is done I am triggering (notification) a setVisibility(View.gone) on that LoadingLayout.

I tried:

```
listview.setFocusable(false);
listview.setClickable(false);
listview.setEnabled(false);
```

But it is not working

I guess the:

```
row.setOnClickListener(this);
```

in the getview method of the adapter is still on?

How do I make it not clickable? Do I get a list of views or something and make them unclickable, but then again. Only the views that are onscreen should be not clickable for that moment? Or is there some other clever method? (I thought the overlaying relativelayout would be clever ... guess not)

Comment: Can't you set the visibility GONE to the listview?

Or set the adapter of the listview null while in that process?

Comment: Are you using a custom arrayadapter?

Comment: Why don't you try to set your rows disabled (using the methods you entered), instead of the listview itself.

Comment: I can set the visibility GONE to the listview, but I thought a transparent look over the default layout would be nice. And yes I'm using a custom arrayadapter. And how do I set the rows disabled temporary? Do I call the getview somewhere else again? Or ...uhm I'm a bit lost here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable in class where you are calling setAdapter to list view as follows

```
OnItemClickListener myAdapterItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO your row onclick actions

    }
};
```

Before loading all the stuff, you can set

```
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(null);
```

After loading it,

```
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(myAdapterItemClickListener);
```

Comment: thanks! Nice solution :D Instead of using the setonclicklistener, I should use the onitemclick.